# assembly 8086 multiply even elements and data segment

Tags: arrays, assembly, emu8086

As a part of my homework I need to initialize two one dimensional arrays, every with 10 2B terms, to multiply every even term with 2. I found some codes, but I dont understand part of initializing arrays in memory.

In next part of example, after this queastion, what does it mean `MOV AX,PODACI`?

- does it moves only address of first term in array `TABELA` and `TABELA1` in `AX`
- or it moves first element in array `TABELA` and `TABELA1` in `AX` (would that be possible in my case, because of size of `AX`, I have dw type of data?)

Is it necessarry to define only arrays in `DATA SEGMENT` if address is used as in question above (I need to find max and min element and according to that plan to define also `min_niz1 dw ?` and `max_niz1 dw ?` in data segment, is that possible if I am using `MOV AX,PODACI`)?

What does it mean `MOV SI, OFFSET TABELA` and `MOV DI, OFFSET TABELA1`, would that move offset address in `SI` and `DI` and what will be in `AL` and `BL` later?

:

```
PODACI  SEGMENT 'DATA'
  TABELA DB 3Fh, 06h, 5Bh, 4Fh, 66h, 6Dh, 7Dh, 27h, 7Fh, 6Fh
  TABELA1 DB 3Fh, 05h, 5Bh, 04h, 03h, 6Dh, 7Dh, 27h, 01h, 6Fh     
PODACI  ENDS

PROGRAM SEGMENT 'CODE'
         ASSUME CS:PROGRAM,DS:PODACI
START:  MOV AX,PODACI
          MOV DS,AX
          MOV SI,0
          MOV DI, 0
          MOV CX, 10 
          MOV SI, OFFSET TABELA
          MOV DI, OFFSET TABELA1
petlja:   MOV AL, [SI]
          MOV BL, [DI] 
          CMP AL, BL
          JNZ nije
          INC DX  
nije:     INC SI
          INC DI
          loop petlja          


PROGRAM ENDS
END START
```

As second part, I need to multiply even terms in arrays with 2, is that possible with this part of code which is below?

```
mov ax,niz1[di]
add ax,ax
mov niz1[di],ax
```

I dont know is that correct way to use only even terms of array, and to put back new value in my array?
I tried to execute this with emu 8086 but solution is not obvious for me.

```
even:
MOV DI, 0
mov ax,niz1[di]
add ax
mov niz1[di],ax
inc di
inc di
cmp di,11
jle even:
```

Comment: your 2nd loop zeros the index (`di`) *inside* the loop, instead of before.  Also, your loop condition is wrong: it will re-enter the loop with `di=10`, but your array is only 5 `word` elements long, right?

Comment: Also, `shl niz1[di], 1` would be more efficient than separate load/shift/store.

Answer (score 1):

### The program you studied

> In next part of example, after this queastion, what does it mean MOV AX,PODACI?

The pair of instructions

```
mov ax, PODACI
mov ds, ax
```

is used to setup the `DS` segment register so that it points at your program's DATA section.

> What does it mean MOV SI, OFFSET TABELA and MOV DI, OFFSET TABELA1, would that move offset address in SI and DI and what will be in AL and BL later?

```
MOV SI, OFFSET TABELA
MOV DI, OFFSET TABELA1
```

will load `SI` and `DI` with the offsets to both arrays, offsets within the DATA section.

```
MOV AL, [SI]
MOV BL, [DI]
```

will load `AL` and `BL` each with one byte-sized element of each array.

### Your task

> I need to initialize two one dimensional arrays, every with 10 2B terms, to multiply every even term with 2

To initialize your new arrays with 10 2B terms, you would use the `DW` directive:

```
niz1 dw 100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000
```

The subscripts for all the elements in this array are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.
The **even terms** are those elements that have array subscripts that are even, so the array elements 0, 2, 4, 6, 8.
Because each array element occupies 2 bytes in memory, the offsets where you'll find these elements are 0, 4, 8, 12, 16. Remember that in assembly programming the value that appears between the square brackets (`niz1[di]`) is **an offset in memory** and not an array subscript like in high level programming languages.

```
  xor di, di        ;Similar to "MOV DI,0".
Even:
  shl niz1[di], 1   ;Doubles this element.
  add di, 4         ;Goes to next 'even' term.
  cmp di, 20        ;Total size of the array.
  jb  Even          ;Repeat as long as we're IN the array.
```

Please note that your solution to multiply even terms in arrays with 2

```
mov ax,niz1[di]
add ax               !!! typo?
mov niz1[di],ax
```

is fine, but doubling through shifting to the left is better.

Good luck turning this into a working program.
(Every program needs an exit to the OS, here it's DOS...)